# Azure Automation DSC - add a VM from a different subscription as a DSC node

Tags: azure, configuration, automation, dsc

I'm trying to onboard a VM to Azure Automation DSC. Can we add a VM from a different subscription as a DSC node ?

Comment: How are you connecting the VM to AA DSC?  ARM template? script? manual install?

Comment: does that matter? @CtrlDot I would expect it to work either way

Comment: @4c74356b41 The Register-AzureRmAutomationDSC command, for example, would not work cross subscription.  The simple answer is yes but he might have to change the onboarding method

Comment: I'm using script to register a node (Register-​Azure​Rm​Automation​Dsc​Node). However, it doesn't have an option to set the Subscription Id. Can you pls let me know how we can configure a node from a different subscription ?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to use the Register-AzureRMAutomationDSC to setup VMs cross subscription.

Following the instructions [located here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding) there are steps to run the Get-AzureRMAutomationRegistrationInfo cmdlet to get the registration key required (of the target Azure Automation account) and then steps to configure the DSC Extension on the target VM.  Please note the instructions are for ASM VMs, but you can use [Set-AzureRMVMExtension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/set-azurermvmextension?view=azurermps-4.1.0) for ASR VMs.

Alternatively, for a more manual approach, follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding#secure-registration) to obtain the registration url and the registration key, and then configure the Local DSC manager using the [Set-DscLocalConfigurationManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/psdesiredstateconfiguration/set-dsclocalconfigurationmanager) cmdlet.